# jQuery set the percentage of repeating-linear-gradient

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The css is as follow

```
-webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(90deg,#ededed 0%,#ededed 7%,white 7%,white 14%,#ededed 14%,#ededed 21%);
```

Is it possible that I am able to set percentage such as 0% or 7% by jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you shouldn't use `-webkit-` prefix anymore.

Second, this is use with `background` property, so you shall do that :

```
$('#MyId').css('background', 'repeating-linear-gradient(90deg,#ededed 0%,#ededed 7%,white 7%,white 14%,#ededed 14%,#ededed 21%)');
```

Here you see it is a string where you could insert variables in. So :

```js
    var firstPercent = 0;
    var secondPercent = 7;
    $('#MyId').css('background', 'repeating-linear-gradient(90deg,#ededed ' + firstPercent  + '%,#ededed ' + secondPercent  + '%,white 7%,white 14%,#ededed 14%,#ededed 21%)');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='MyId'>HERE IS MY GRADIENT</div>
```

[W3Schools link for gradients](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try it later.

Comment: Fine, just don't forget to accept and to vote up if it fits your question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this property works or not. but it should be like this we can concatenate using `+`.

```
var x=0;
var y=7%;
$('#Id').css('background', 'repeating-linear-gradient(90deg,#ededed '+x+'%,#ededed '+y+'%,white '+y+'%,white '+2y+'%,#ededed '+2y+'%,#ededed '+x3y+'%)');
```